# What switch do I use so as to be open when pressed, and closed otherwise?

Tags: switches

I need a switch that turns the circuit off when pressed on, but turns on when lifted off. this is to go under a lid I am making to turn on the lights when lifted. What is this switch called? it is the the only missing piece of the puzzle...

Update: I need a switch for one circuit. low voltage @4.5v. What is the switch called, or is the more than one switch needed.

Comment: "Push to Break"

Comment: I've seen such type pushbutton switches are used in refriedgerator light. When the fridge door open, the switch unpressed, and the switch turns-on (light glows-up)

Comment: Or a double-throw switch with just the right pin wired. Might give you additional options from the manufacturers catalogs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a Normally Closed push button - the switch contacts will be connected unless the button is pressed.  A single pole, double throw button may be easier to find - that would give you both Normally Closed and Normally Open contacts.

A common name for a switch that is operated by things rather than directly by people is MicroSwitch (TM Honeywell, I think).  Microswitches are available with a wide variety of actuating levers.

Comment: The generic term is a snap action limit switch but the 'microswitch' trade name has moved into common use as rolls off the tongue easier.

Answer (score 2):

Search push switch on wikipedia. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_switch

There is mention of 2 basic type of push-button switch

**1. Normally Open / Push to make** (the well-known one)

**2. Normally Closed / Push to break.** (that you're seeking)

[image: Schematic symbol push to break]

Here is the circuit-symbol of 2 kinds of push-button switch. The symbols carry a logical-hint of their actions.

Answer (score 1):

You require a Normally closed SPST switch. There are switches available, which illuminates when the switch is pressed. A very good example is an Emergency switch, which breaks off the circuit when pressed and also illuminates RED(usually) to give an indication that it has been activated.

Something similar to this
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/A165E-LS-24D-01/Z1425-ND/456231